# Why do we need TN liquid crystal to switch on/off a pixel?

Tags: lcd

I have been reading this wikipedia page about [LCDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquid-crystal_display) where they explain that we use TN Liquid Crystal to switch off/on a pixel. That made sense.

**But when reading on [IPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPS_panel), they say they can control intensities of R,G,B LEDs. So, why do we need TN liquid crystal to switch on/off a pixel?**
If we want to switch a pixel off, we can just set the intensity of that Diode to zero.

Or am I missing something?

Comment: Em, which Wikipedia page? If there's a page section link please post that - in your question, not in the comments.

Comment: Where are you reading this?

Comment: No mention of RGB LEDs or their control appears in the Wikipedia pages you linked.  [If you change the color mix of the backlight LED, you'll change the observed color temperature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backlight#LED_backlights)... but the backlight doesn't have an LED per-pixel.

Comment: yes the control system is not there. but there are few backlits that they discussed. one of them is rgb leds which we use now in moat devices. I was reading different articles bro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find a reference to LED on the IPS article other than for backlighting.

- Both systems are allowing transmission / blocking of light by orthagonal (right-angled) polarisation of the liquid crystal.
- In the case of the colour display one white backlight illuminates the LCD. The individual pixels have colour filters, RGB, and the LCD acts as a variable "dimmer" to each pixel. The brightness of the backlight itself is not adjustable pixel by pixel.
- The monochrome LCD is simpler. One backlight (if required), one background polariser and the liquid crystals on top of that.

Comment: for example to produce orange color, we need different intensities of R,G,B . So these intensities are not controlled by Diode circuit right? it will be controlled by the amount of voltage applied (Electric filed) to the electrodes implanted in glass substrate right?

Comment: Correct. It could even be a cold-cathode-fluorescent backlight so there wouldn't be an LED in sight! Applying a signal to the segment or pixel will modulate the light on that pixel. If you have some polarising sunglasses you can check the effect by popping one lens out and rotating it in front of the other. It will go from translucent to opaque with a 90° rotation.

Comment: awesome man thanks. I was thinking that, that is its purpose, but was unable to find any source to verify it. In that same wiki page there was a video which says about these intensities but doesn't explain and the pictorial representation confused me.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Lcd-engineerguy.ogv. Thanks man big time